# Does the operating system affect the firmware

Tags: debian, firmware

I don’t know if this is the right place to ask this question but still please help me

My operating system (Debian) says that I have missing firmware something about i918). Debian documentation says that I can download it with the isenkram-cli package. But isn’t the manufacturer of the computer the one who gives out firmware updates? **Doesn’t the operating system not affect the firmware?**

Comment: CPU microcode patches and firmware updates can be updated by the OS, for example on Linux there's LVFS to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays lots of hardware needs firmware which isn’t stored alongside the hardware itself (in flash or ROM); the hardware expects its driver, running on the main operating system, to load it.

This is what the “missing firmware” message is referring to: the `i915` driver lists the firmware it can potentially need (run `sudo modinfo i915 | grep '^firmware'` to see the list), and the system sees that the hardware needs the `i915` driver but that at least some of the firmware isn’t available. Note that the `i915` driver supports lots of different chipsets, with different firmware requirements; so the “missing firmware” message isn’t necessarily a show-stopper.

The firmware *is* provided by the hardware manufacturer, but on Linux it takes a circuitous route to get to your system: the manufacturers make them available typically in [the Linux firmware repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/), and from there it is [packaged for your distribution](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/firmware-nonfree).

Comment: Please can I also ask why did the drivers go missing? I installed this version one month ago and it shouldn’t be outdated. Thanks